# Svg fill color update

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm very new to HTML, SVG, javascript and all what is web programming.

I need to do a synoptic webpage to display different information's on my data acquisition.

I have a python script which read data from physical devices and I'd like to update these acquisition on a web page. My python script can change svg file fill color of different graphical components.

If , for example, this is my svg file:

```
<svg width="800" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="Layer_1">
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="386" width="527" y="94" x="150"     stroke="#231F20" fill="yellow"/>
  <rect id="svg_2" height="386" width="527" y="114" x="450"     stroke="#231F20" fill="yellow"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

how could I upload new color on the svg file object without reloading the page?
For example I'd like to change id="svg_1" fill color from "yellow" to red according to my python scrip. How can I do it and display immediately?

Thanks,
Marcin

Comment: Sounds like your doing IOT stuff. Look into SSE - Server Sent Events. https://www.google.com/search?q=sse+python